# Laravel task scheduler runs only when doing the command "php artisan schedule:run"

Tags: scheduled-tasks, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to create a Scheduler in Laravel 5.8 on my localhost, but it only runs when I use the following command.

```
php /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

php artisan schedule:run
```

and not runs every minute as i defined

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $good = new Grocery();
        $good->name = 'good';
        $good->type = 'type';
        $good->price = '222';
        $good->save();
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

Data is stored in the database, but I should run the command every time.
Nothing is unique in the database.

Comment: Is the first command added to your cron?

Comment: i didn't get what you said.
can you explain more,please.

Comment: Your `schedule:run` needs to be added to your cronjob using `crontab -e`. This will allow you to set the command to run every minute. Laravel is then responsible for seeing if your scheduled command should run.

Comment: Type `crontab -e` into your terminal.

Comment: thanks bro, this helped.

Comment: I'll add as answer.

Comment: would be nice .

Comment: Added as an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `schedule:run` needs to be added to your cronjob.

This can be done by typing `crontab -e`. Once done you should enter the command to be executed every minute:

```
* * * * * php /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will set the command to run every minute. Your application is then responsible for seeing if your scheduled command should run.

Comment: If running Homestead in vagrant, would this be run inside that instance? e.g. `vagrant ssh`